# Laravel eloquent builders merge with OR condition

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I have built multiple Builder instances. Each of them contains some  complex "where" condition.

[image]

I need to merge them into one big Builder to make only one request to the database.  They should all be merged as   ( ( builder 1 ) OR (builder 2) ....)  where each builder N expands to some SQL queries.

In Yii I used this function [mergeWith](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#mergeWith-detail) . I can't find similar functionality in Laravel. Could you please point me out how to do it properly via eloquent?

**EDITED**

This is how looks a [single Builder](http://kagda.ru/i/350141935584_11-12-2017-00:49:18_3501.png),

All other builders contain just different words in Where clause.

Comment: try to use "unions" https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#unions . I cant's see other way with laravel in this moment. I hope I have been helpful

Comment: I can't see the way how I'm supposed to pass  join condition  like "OR " or "AND" for where clause

Comment: It might help if you actually post the queries you're attempting to join.

Comment: Edited, added an example of single query, which is contained inside one of  builders. And this builder needs to be joined with other bulders using  OR operator (or and  , depends on situation)

Comment: I feel like it has something to do with Parameter Grouping and closure, still trying out to figure out how

Comment: - use advance where clauses

Answer (score 0):

Aha! Found it. This is how  I guess it should be. 
Everything what is inside closure is getting inserted into parenthesis.
And we get in the  result (  (..)   OR  (...)  ) etc

```
   $builderMain = collect($searchWords)->reduce(function($carry, $searchWord) 
    {
      return  $carry->orWhere(function($query) use ($searchWord)
        {

          $query->where('...');
          $query->where('...');
          $query->where('...');
          $query->where('...');
           ......
      };
  ....
  }, BigMoney::query());
```

If there is a better alternative I will accept your answer. Still open for suggestions